# What are all the Shakespearean themes in Gargoyles?

Tags: analysis, gargoyles

I heard and read many times that *Gargoyles* had many Shakespearean themes in the show and was able to track easily. [Macbeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbeth) arc is covered with [Macbeth mac Findlaech](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Macbeth_(Gargoyles)) and [Othello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Othello) with [Coldstone](http://gargoyles.wikia.com/wiki/Coldstone).

What are other Shakespearean themes in Gargoyles?

Comment: Well, are you looking for Shakespearean *themes* or just references to Shakespeare's works? It's currently a little unclear with your wording and tag choice contradicting the examples you provide.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson both

Comment: Then I'm afraid it might be a little broad (or broader than it *already* looked like).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson looks short to me as per nog's finding https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47923459#47923459

Comment: So it *is* more references than themes you're after then if you tailored it to an existing answer?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson is it not most of those reference become overall theme too ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, thither art a lot of references to Shakespeare's worketh in  *Gargoyles*.

- Season 1 Episode 09

  - [Enter Macbeth](https://gargwiki.net/Enter_Macbeth) - Macbeth mac Findlaech is introduced. This is a reference to William Shakespear's play *[Macbeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macbeth)*.
- Season 2 Episode 03

  - [Legion](https://gargwiki.net/Legion) - In the end credits, Future Coldfire and Coldsteel are named as [Desdemona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desdemona) and [Iago](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iago). These two are characters from Shakespeare's play [*Othello*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Othello). Coldfire is the robotic body made by Xanatos to house Desdemona's soul. Coldfire is called Desdemona but Coldsteel is not called by the Iago but just given the name in the voice credits.
- Season 2 Episode 04

  - [A Lighthouse in the Sea of Time](https://gargwiki.net/A_Lighthouse_in_the_Sea_of_Time) - Macbeth mac Findlaech 's henchmen are named as "[Banquo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banquo)" and "[Fleance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleance#In_Macbeth)" in the voice credits. These are again characters from the play *Macbeth*.
  - Macbeth mac Findlaech's alias is recognized by Jeffrey Robbins. It is Lennox Macduff, which is obtained by joining two character names [Lord Macduff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macduff_(Macbeth)) and [Lennox](https://www.playshakespeare.com/macbeth/characters/3004-lennox) which are again characters from *Macbeth*.
- Season 2 Episode 05

  - [The Mirror](https://gargwiki.net/The_Mirror) - Puck is introduced. Two characters from Shakespeare's _ A Midsummer Night's Dream_ i.e., [Oberon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberon) and [Titania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titania) are first mentioned.
  - Brooklyn and Elisa both mention *A Midsummer Night's Dream*.
- Season 2 episode 08

  - [Vows](https://gargwiki.net/Vows) - Xanatos says to his father, "Reason not the need", a quote from [*King Lear*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Lear).
- Season 2 Episode 09, 10 and 11

  - City of Stone [Part One](https://gargwiki.net/City_of_Stone_Part_One) - The Weird Sisters are introduced. This is an allusion to [Three Witches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Witches) *Macbeth*.
  - [Part Three](https://gargwiki.net/City_of_Stone_Part_Three) - The Weird sisters say "Double, double, toil and trouble/ Fire burn and cauldron bubble" which are famous lines from the play Macbeth. They greet Macbeth and Duncan with the words "All hail [Duncan/Macbeth], King of Scotland, and father of the king hereafter!" which are lines from *Macbeth*.
  - At Macbeth and Gruoch's wedding, Bodhe introduces them as "Lord and Lady Macbeth".
  - One of Duncan's henchmen is named "Macduff" in the voice credits. As said above already, Macduff is the name of a character from *Macbeth*
- Season 2 Episode 13

  - [High Noon](https://gargwiki.net/High_Noon) -  Lexington uses the names "Othello", "Desdemona", and "Iago" as password attempts when trying to re-activate Coldstone. As mentioned already, these are characters from *Othello*.
- Season 2 Episode 35

  - [Heritage](https://gargwiki.net/Heritage) -  Elisa adapts the line "There are more things in heaven and earth..." from Shakespeare's famous tragedy *[Hamlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamlet)*, when speaking to Natsilane.
- Season 2 Episode 42

  - [Ill Met By Moonlight](https://gargwiki.net/Ill_Met_By_Moonlight) - Episode title is  a quote from *[A Midsummer Night's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Midsummer_Night%27s_Dream)*.
  - Oberon and Titania are appeared for the first time.
  - Character Ophelia is first named. She is named after [Opehlia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophelia)) from *Hamlet*.
  - At the end of the episode, Goliath says "All's well that ends well, then." which is an allusion to [*All's well that ends well*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All%27s_Well_That_Ends_Well).
  - Oberon's line "The game is afoot" comes from the "Once more unto the breach" speech from *[Henry V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_V_(play))*. This occurs in Act III Scene I.
- Season 2 Episode 43

  - [Future Tense](https://gargwiki.net/Future_Tense) - The Xanatos Program adapts the line "Alas, poor Yorick" from *Hamlet*.
- Season 2 Episode 45

  - [The Gathering Part Two](https://gargwiki.net/The_Gathering_Part_Two) -  Oberon says that when the humans in Manhattan awake the morning after his assault upon the Eyrie Building, the strange events from the previous night will seem to them only *A midsummer Night's Dream*.

Besides these, there are a few mentions in the comics too.

Taken from [Gargoyles Wiki](https://gargwiki.net/William_Shakespeare#Shakespearean_allusions_in_Gargoyles).